Environment settings not found in K8 .NetCore API
I have a K8 cluster of .Net Core 8 APIs that is deployed using a Github action yml script and uses K8 manifest files generated from a docker-compose file.
I have appsettings.json that I want to override fields for. In my ProgramExtensions.cs I ensure that as long as I set them as environment variables, they will be used over the appsettings value.
I am not sure where I would add these variables, I have tried to add them to Github secrets and then use them in the Github Actions workflow.yml like shown below:
jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
        DATABASEUSERNAME : ${{ secrets.DATABASEUSERNAME }}
        DATABASEPASSWORD : ${{ secrets.DATABASEPASSWORD }}

Once deployed, the API is failing because it cannot find the secrets in the snipet above. Can anyone point me to the correct way to do this?

There may be other ways, but did you try creating an .env file manually as a step in your workflow and pass in your repository secrets? Ex: - run: touch .env && echo VARIABLE=${{ secrets.VARIABLE }} >> .env. This is the recommended way on the Docker Compose documentation

Amazing, please add as answer

It may not be the only solution, but as suggested in the Docker Compose documentation, you can create an .env file manually as a step in your workflow and pass in your repository secrets.

An .env file in Docker Compose is a text file used to define environment variables that should be made available to Docker containers when running docker compose up. This file typically contains key-value pairs of environment variables, and it allows you to centralize and manage configuration in one place. The .env file is useful if you have multiple environment variables you need to store.

Example:
 steps:
 - run: |
     touch .env
     echo VARIABLE=${{ secrets.VARIABLE }} >> .env

